# Type ] in the title of a proposition

Tags: pdftex

I'm using pdflatex. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}[Algebraic Structure of $F[x]$]
      
    This is a proposition.
\end{proposition}
\end{document}
```

But this didn't work

[image]

Comment: Try putting the brackets in an extra set of braces so the close bracket isn't interpreted as as the end of the optional argument: `\begin{proposition}[Algebraic Structure of {$F[x]$}]`

Comment: Or you can group only that bracket `{]}`

Comment: @antshar you can here but not in general: `{]}` is a mathord not a mathclose so will have different spacing in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}[Algebraic Structure of $F\lbrack x\rbrack$]
This is a proposition.
\end{proposition}
\end{document}
```

[image]